# How to make a cast iron shader that has scrapes?

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders

Attached is an image of my project so far. How could I make this have a scratched texture across the hull and up structure to make it realistic.[image]

Comment: I would say the same thing back: A picture of what you want could be helpful.

Comment: Something like this - https://www.zedge.net/wallpaper/79d41714-3f4b-3a56-898b-87266a14fad3

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=metal+scratches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to use the *Box* option of the *Image Texture* node:

- Find a scratch texture image:

[image]

- Create this node chain: *Texture Coordinate > Mapping > Image Texture > ColorRamp >* plugged into the *Roughness* socket of the *Principled BSDF*. In the *Image Texture*, switch from *Flat* to *Box* so that the image is projected on all the axis. If needed, increase the *Blend* so that no seam is visible. Play with the *ColorRamp* to increase or decrease the *Roughness*. Choose the *Principled Base Color*:

[image]

- Here is the kind of effect you can get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the shader editor , increase the Metallic value and decrease the roughness , and then get some scratches from net , nd then attach them with a displacement

Comment: Could you send a picture of the shader tree diagram.

Comment: @Shikha Mittal use the answer section to post simple and detailed answer which even a beginner can understand. I would appreciate it if you edit your question and more details and some images.