# where should i mark a seam onto my mesh?

Tags: uv

[image]

Where i should mark a seam so my texture doesn't look discontinuous in a certain area.

Comment: you can add one in the bottom , and probably one in the back

Comment: Think of how the material would be in real life. There is always a seam if it is fabric, or a place where all of the parts are put together.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the seams on a part that won't be visible on rendering. You can't avoid discontinuity with this kind of object, unless you give corrections afterwards and recreate continuity with a *Clone* brush for example, but it will depend on the nature of your pattern, if it's a big pattern (like big flowers) it seems hard to achieve.

As you can see here I put the seam along the back of the cube, so that it will be hidden in render. For this kind of pattern it would be very hard to create a continuous texture:

[image]

Comment: i see, although i wanted the texture to be continuous all around, because im making an asset for my game that can be moved in any way, but i guess i"ll have to do something else. Thank you for the help though!

Comment: there may be a solution but please show your texture and even share it so that we can see and maybe give a try

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/F9iCeJ7

Comment: oh ok so it has nothing to do with the example I gave, maybe try this technique: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191621/how-to-make-a-cast-iron-shader-that-has-scrapes/191654#191654

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Tz6xmy7

Comment: So how does it work? Maybe share your file if you meet any problem, don't forget to pack your image: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: sorry about that, i added the wrong file;) also i cant pack the image with it due to an unused texture, not being found or some error like that.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2JQV8pn7" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2JQV8pn7/)

Comment: you didn't pack any image but anyway I've tried with another one, and actually it works fine if you follow the method I give here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191621/how-to-make-a-cast-iron-shader-that-has-scrapes/191654#191654

Comment: actually i did use that method in a different save, i did notice that the texture looked alot better.

Comment: I don't think you can get much better with texture, another way would be to use procedural texture, it depends on the level of realism you need, also do you need some close-up shots on your object etc...

Comment: well the whole point of the model, is to be used as an asset in a game i plan to make, so i want it to look like its comfortable and made of material of a chair, so not that realistic, but to give that sort of illusion. the model, would be pretty close to the player character too.